# QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 while saving Customizable Options

Tags: database, custom-options, magento-2.1.7

Each time i try to add Customizable Options to a product i got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`thailandnamage`.`catalog_product_option_title`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_OPT_TTL_OPT_ID_CAT_PRD_OPT_OPT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`option_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_option` (`option_id`) ON DELETE CA),
query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_option_title` (`option_id`, `store_id`, `title`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Which says that magento cannot add orphan row to `catalog_product_option_title`, because the option_id don't exist into `catalog_product_option` but since it is new entry, why it can't add the row on that table first ? If the bug happen since the beginning i would understand, but why this bug start to happen ?

something wrong with the db ?

It start to occurs after i tried to add an article but the page didn't finish the task (504 error).

I have check the db, and it look ok... i even did a backup of the db from date before the bug occurs.

Does anyone know how was to check/fix ?

NB: When i try to import custom option from an other product i got this error (after saving the product):

```
No such entity.
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't coming from the db at all but from a patch i used...

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8251

All these bug are a problem for magento. you need to patch the CMS to fix bug, but it creates other bugs... it never end. I am a bit disappointed by magento 2 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I solved it just by adding a couple of lines of code in

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Repository.php
```

in the save method:

```
if ($option->getOptionId()) {
    ...
} else
    $option->setOptionId(null);
```